# How to insert a widget with a JavaScript in WordPress pages/posts

Tags: javascript, wordpress, widget

I am a complete newbie to web development…

So I wanted to show some air quality data on my new WordPress website. I used iqair to create the below custom widget code with javascript and tried so many different tutorials and plugins with no success at all.

```
<div name=”airvisual_widget” key=”xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx”></div>
<script type=”text/javascript” src=”http://cdn.airvisual.net/assets/widgets/widget_v3.0.js”></script&gt;
```

this seems really really difficult. Can someone help me out, please?

Comment: Well, you could just use the **Custom HTML** widget to insert this code into your sidebar. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: hi thanks, it turned out that the widget is not using HTTPS, and my site can't render the output (because my site uses HTTPS). I simply added tiny little "s" in the code and it works :D